# Why does timestamp() show an extra microsecond compared with subtracting 1970-01-01?

Tags: python, datetime, floating-point, timestamp

The following differ by 1 microsecond :

```py
In [37]: datetime(2514, 5, 30, 1, 53, 4, 986754, tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc) - datetime(1970,1,1, tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc)
Out[37]: datetime.timedelta(days=198841, seconds=6784, microseconds=986754)

In [38]: datetime(2514, 5, 30, 1, 53, 4, 986754, tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc).timestamp()
Out[38]: 17179869184.986755
```

The number of microseconds in `986754` in the first case, and `986755` in the second.

Is this just Python floating point arithmetic error, or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: You might find the `numpy` implementation of `datetime64()` of interest.  `print(numpy.datetime64('2514-05-30T01:53:04.986754'))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a floating-point approximation. If you just type

```
17179869184.986754
```

into Python, you will get

```
17179869184.986755
```

The former is not expressible with the precision available to Python's float type.

Answer (score 2):

Given that  `17179869184.986754` is between `2^34` and `2^35`, and a [double precision float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) has a 53 bit significand, you get

```
(2**35 - 2**34) / 2**53 = 1.9073486328125e-06
```

i.e. your precision is well above the microsecond (meaning worse than).

- this is *not* specific to Python; it's a property of the IEEE 754 floating point number implementation
- the representation of Unix time as floating point number of seconds since 1970-01-01 is not generally less accurate than one microsecond - it depends on the absolute value of the number

Comment: There's no real advantage in using NumPy here: Python's `datetime.datetime` doesn't use floating-point internally either. The issue only arises when converting to a `float` timestamp.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I agree; I'll probably remove that part. It doesn't help anyway, of you want fractional seconds.

Comment: As the page you link to says, the double-precision format has 53-bit significands, not 52. 52 bits are encoded in the primary significand field, and one is encoded via the exponent field. Mathematically, they behave as if they have 53-bit significands. Also, the preferred term for the fraction portion of a floating-point number is “signifcand.” “Mantissa” is an old term for the fraction portion of a logarithm. Significands are linear; mantissas are logarithmic.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thank you for your comment, I've tried to address it. Please feel free to edit the post if you'd like to improve it further. In general, I think my point still holds; for one, this is not specific to Python and second, the floating point representation is not *generally* less accurate than a microsecond. I think the now "accepted" other answer falls short of clarifying this, that's why I added this post.

Answer (score -1):

It an error of 1.37109375 usecs due to conversion to a 64 bit float:

> > > print("%100.100f\n" % (17179869184.986754))
> > > 17179869184.9867553710937500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

> > > 17179869184.98675537109375
> > > 17179869184.986755

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).